# add new custom option in cart not work while adding configurable product using observer

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, event-observer, custom-options, quoteitem

when I `addtocart` simple product and added new custom option using `checkout_cart_product_add_after`,it works perfect and cart displays new custom option in cart but my new custom option does not display while adding configurable product,it display configurable attribute lable and its value('color: blue') but my new custom option does not see.

My **config.xml**

```
<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <test_checkout_product_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>test/observer</class>
                        <method>addTestInfo</method>
                    </test_checkout_product_observer>
                </observers>
</checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

My **Observer.php**

```
public function addTestInfo($observer)
    {
        $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();


            $additionalOptions = array(array(
                            'code'  => 'test_shop_info',
                            'label' => 'label1',
                            'value' => 'value1',
                        ));

                        $quoteItem->addOption(array(
                            'code'  => 'additional_options',
                            'value' => serialize($additionalOptions),
                        ));         
        return $this;                   
    }
```

What I want:
My new custom option should display in cart while adding configurable product.

This above code works only simple product not for configurable product.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution by folllowing link.

It will be used `catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options` observer

http://sonimanthan228.blogspot.in/2015/12/add-new-custom-option-using-observer-in.html